# datetime subtract .net

Tags: .net

i want to get datetime for 2days before. i.e) how to subtract 2 days from datetime.now

Answer (score 27):

I think you are just looking for:

```
DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2);
```

Answer (score 9):

or try:

```
DateTime.Now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another solution:

```
DateTime twoDays = DateTime.Now.Subtract(new TimeSpan(2,0,0,0));
```